# KeycloakOidcConfiguration load during application start and load values from database

Tags: shiro, pac4j

I would like to load my Keycloak Settings dynamically from my database.
I would like to do this:

- Start my application
- Load from my database required information for the `KeycloakOidcConfiguration` Object
- Set the values which I got from my database to the `KeycloakOidcConfiguration`.

I tried to load it during App Start like this:

```
InputStream inputStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/shiro-web.ini");
Ini ini = new Ini();
ini.load(inputStream);
ini.setSectionProperty("main", "oidcConfig.realm", keycloakApplicationProvider.getRealm());
```

But this seems not working, I got this error message:

> Caused by: org.pac4j.core.exception.TechnicalException: realm cannot
> be blank

In my shiro.ini I have this config:

```
#Keycloack
oidcConfig = org.pac4j.oidc.config.KeycloakOidcConfiguration
```

My question would be: how can I get the **current KeycloakOidcConfiguration**, which is using from Pac4j / Shiro?
It seems for me at the moment I change (set) the wrong KeycloakOidcConfiguration.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

To load the Keycloak settings dynamically from your database, you need to create a `CustomOidcClient` and a `CustomOidcConfiguration` which initializes itself from the database.

Comment: Can I not use the `oidcConfig = org.pac4j.oidc.config.KeycloakOidcConfiguration` and `keycloakOidClient = org.pac4j.oidc.client.KeycloakOidcClient` which I defined in shiro.ini ? I need to load this instances from those classes than during start from my application and change the properties (info from my database...) ?

Comment: When loading from shiro.ini, I think the client/config is lazzily initialized somehow and the realm is missing. Can you copy/paste the full stack trace?

Comment: Yeah and the question would be how can I get this current client/config instances which are in use... and than just change the field values (realmname etc.) ?